# Alter does not working before redirect + controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have code:

```
public ActionResult Inner(simpleQA.Models.Post model)
    {
        if(simpleQA.User.Current != null)
        {
                simpleQA.Post objPostAns = new Post();
                objPostAns.TypeId = 4;
                objPostAns.Content = model.ContentAnswesr;
                objPostAns.RelatePostId = model.RelatePostId;
                objPostAns.CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
                objPostAns.CreateBy = simpleQA.User.Current.Id;
                objPostAns.Save();
                return View("");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Please Login");
            Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        return View("/");
    }
```

I try `Respon.write` alter before redirect but it does not working.
Tell me one alter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use response.write in an MVC controller. The controller can only pass data to the view.

What you should do instead of `Response.Redirect` is redirect to a login View:

```
return RedirectToAction("Login");
```

(better use built in (forms)authentication because it'll send the user to the login form automatically and after login back to the page he meant to go to)

Comment: Right... thanks sooo.!
But i don't no after login back to the page ... can help me? ^^" thank pro.